# Does audio (mp3) play while downloading with html5's audo tag

Tags: mp3, html5-audio

When a web page downloads an MP3 file via the HTML5 tag:

```
<audio autoplay="autoplay">
   <source src="../blah" type="audio/mp3"/>
</audio>
```

Does the audio play while (at the same time) the MP3 is download? Or, does the file download first then the sound is played?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

No doubt the answer may vary from device and web browser, but if you are asking if you can play the html5 audio tag before it's completed download, then yes you can. (Tested in Firefox/Chrome)

The sound is played as it buffers, in essence streamed.